# Given $N$, is there a formula for $card( \{(m,n)\, s.t.\, m\cdot n \leq N \} )$?

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic

The formula is also equivalent to :

$$ \sum_{m=1}^N \left \lfloor \frac{N}{m} \right \rfloor $$

An interpretation would be to count the discrete rectangles with total area inferior to N. But aside from that, I don't really see how to express this...

Of course, it should not be hard to compute, but I was curious to see if there is a formula for this.

On the same topic, is the following equality true ?
Basically the same formula with bounding both $m$ and $n$ (and not just their product). All variables are integers.

$$ \text{card}\left( \Big\{(m,k)\, s.t.\, m\cdot k \leq N, m\in[1,M] , k\in[1,K] \Big\}\right) = \sum_{m=1}^{\min(M,N)}\min\left(K,\left \lfloor \frac{N}{m} \right \rfloor\right)$$

Comment: The sum of floor functions is a formula! It is called a quasi-polynomial. See here for more on this fascinating piece of mathematics: http://www.oberlin.edu/faculty/kwoods/research/ubiquitous_qps_full.pdf

Comment: You probably also want to make some restrictions on $m,n$.  Are they positive integers? Then the formula may be off. For $N=3$, I get $\lfloor 3 \rfloor + \lfloor 3/2 \rfloor + \lfloor 1 \rfloor = 5$ while the only solutions are $(1,1), (1,2), (2,1)$.

Comment: Yes of course $m,n$ are integer. I was curious to see for an expression with no sum...

Comment: your last equation seems to be slightly off, I guess you mean $n\in [1,K]$?

Comment: Yes thanks, I corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [Dirichlet's divisor problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function) and is a famous problem in number theory.  From Wikipedia:

> The divisor summatory function is defined as $$D(x)=\sum_{n\le x} d(n) = \sum_{j,k \atop jk\le x} 1$$ where $$d(n)=\sigma_0(n) = \sum_{j,k \atop jk=n} 1$$ is the divisor function. The divisor function counts
>   the number of ways that the integer n can be written as a product of
>   two integers.

The formula with quasi-polynomials is not correct.  In fact, nobody knows how to derive an explicit formula.  Asymptotics have been studied, though.

Comment: Well, that answers my question, thanks.

Comment: Well, it's not exactly an unsolved problem. The asymptotics are known, and bounds on the error term are known. The unsolved part is finding the best possible bound on the error term.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Granted. I removed the adjective "unsolved".